# Why are there only five states in Lifecycle in android?

Tags: android, lifecycle

I had always thought that onStop had a corresponding state of STOPPED, but when I looked at Lifecycle.state, there are only five. There are no STOPPED OR PAUSED, OR RESTARTED.
My question is if there is not a STOPPED state, why is onStop able to work?

Answer (score 0):

[`Lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle) keeps tracks of 2 things: `Lifecycle.Event` and `Lifecycle.State`. The component starts in the `INITIALIZED` state. Each event will transition the lifecycle component into the next state.

In the state `Lifecycle.State.STARTED`, the event `Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP` leads to the state `Lifecycle.State.CREATED`.

The event-state graph looks like:

```
[INITIALIZED] —ON_CREATE—> [CREATED] —ON_START—> [STARTED] —ON_RESUME—> [RESUMED] —ON_DESTROY—> [DESTROYED]
                               ^                    | ^                     |
                               └——————ON_STOP———————┘ └———————ON_PAUSE——————┘
```

The `onStop()` callback does not lead to a stopped state because it represents an *event* instead of a *state*. The `ON_STOP` event leads to the `CREATED` state.

Comment: According to your graph, when you receive the ON_STOP event, an Activity will actually be running shortly. I do not understand this. How do you decide to stop sending UI updates when your Activity never stops.

Comment: What do you mean by "an Activity will actually be running shortly"? When `onStop()` is called, that means the OS is no longer showing your Activity and user input will no longer be received by your activity. It is expected that the developer stops any threads/asynchronous calls that update the UI. See [Activity Lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#activity-lifecycle) for more information.

Comment: Let me explain it this way: Activity A is running. I open Activity B and A is stopped. Activity A emits the ON_STOP event and goes from the STARTED state to what state? I can see that the arrow points to the CREATED state. This is confusing. You go from STARTED TO CREATED and emit the ON_STOP event. Well, I am lost.

Comment: And here is a quote from [link](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-activity-lifecycle#5) Each `state` in the activity lifecycle has a corresponding callback method you can override in your Activity class. The core set of lifecycle methods are: onCreate()onStart()onPause()onRestart()onResume()onStop()onDestroy(). Where are the promised corresponding PAUSED, RESTARTED and STOPPED states.

Comment: The link is a bit misleading and people often conflate events with states. For now, I'm going to focus on why `ON_STOP` leads to the `CREATED` state. When the `ON_CREATE` event is sent, it means that the app is not in view and `onCreate()` has executed once. When `ON_STOP` event is sent, it means that the app is no longer in view (and `onCreate()` has executed once). Observe that both results are the same. Therefore, we can say that both lead to the same state. `ON_CREATE` leads to `CREATED` and `ON_STOP` leads to `CREATED`.

Comment: If it makes it more intuitive, then one can rename the `CREATED` state to `STOPPED`. So, `ON_CREATE` leads to `STOPPED` and `ON_STOP` leads to `STOPPED`. Honestly, that naming convention makes a lot more sense to me as the next event from the `STOPPED` state would be `ON_START`.

Comment: To be clear, I am mostly regurgitating the [`Lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle.State#CREATED) documentation. "`CREATED`: Created state for a LifecycleOwner. For an android.app.Activity, this state is reached in two cases: after `onCreate` call; right before `onStop` call."

Comment: Thank you very much. I can only guess that once ON_STOP is issued, we are moved to a 'fake' CREATED state. And if the Activity is not killed, it can go back to STARTED immediately when called.